# Openstreet map shows blank portion when increase length

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

I am displaying openstreet map on my web page with origional dimensions 970/256(width/height). It works fine. I have also added a button on the page. When user presses this button the map width increases spanning the total width of the page. But when the map width increases, right portion of map seems to be blanked as shown in following image:

[image]

Here is Javascript code to be triggered when clicked on button:

```
$(function() {
            $("#hide").click(function() {
                if($(this).attr("value") == "Hide")
                {
                    document.getElementById('hide').value="Show";
                    $("#hide").html('Show');
                    $('#tabs').hide();

                    var pos;
                    pos = $("#map").offset();
                    $("#map").animate({
                        left: "-" + (pos.left-50) + "px",
                    });

                    $("#map").width(1350);
                }   
                else{
                    document.getElementById('hide').value="Hide";
                    $("#hide").html('Hide');
                    $('#tabs').show('fast');

                    var pos;
                    pos = $("#map").offset();
                    $("#map").animate({
                        left: "+" + (pos.left+50) + "px",
                    });

                    $("#map").width(970);
                }   

            });
        });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `map.invalidateSize();` after size changing.

```
$(function() {
    $('#hide').click(function() {
        var button = $(this), mapStyles;

        if(button.attr('value') === 'Hide') {
            button.attr('value', 'Show');
            button.html('Show');
            $('#tabs').hide();

            pos = $('#map').offset();
            mapStyles = {
                left: '-' + (pos.left - 50) + 'px',
                width: '1350px'
            };
        } else {
            button.attr('value', 'Hide');
            button.html('Hide');
            $('#tabs').show('fast');  

            pos = $('#map').offset();
            mapStyles = {
                left: '+' + (pos.left + 50) + 'px',
                width: '970px'
            };
        }   

        $('#map').animate(mapStyles, function () {
            // there are you must have map varable witch retirned by L.Map()
            map.invalidateSize();
        });
    }); 
});
```

**PS**

- Better use jquery `val` method for inputs and `data` for other instead `attr`.
- You already have `#hide` element as `this`.
- If you do not mix different qoutes then code look better.